# Mouseovers on image maps in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mouseover, imagemap, mouseout

I'm having a problem with IE (who isn't) executing my javascript. Are there any known issues with attaching mouseovers to image maps in IE8? I'm not seeing any similar posts.

For instance, here is the HTML in one of my pages:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="2,575,389,637,388,19,1,74" alt="Main Page" onmouseover="fade('indexpop')" onmouseout="fade('indexpop');" />
</map>
```

Pretty simple. In every browser but IE, this excecutes the "fade" function to fade in (or out) a div with some information.

The function itself is [here](http://www.tcmulder.com/port/javascript/popups.js), but I don't think the issue is with the function but with the mouseovers.

Thanks,

-tcm <><

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to put the mouseovers on the IMG (image) instead of the image map ?

Comment: On most pages of the website I have one img with multiple areas on the map, so I can't simply attach it to the img.

Comment: Actually you could bind events to image and use event delegation http://mark-story.com/posts/view/speed-up-javascript-event-handling-with-event-delegation-and-bubbling